# Protocol Kit tutorial not working for me - following tutorial step by step

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/learn/safe-core-account-abstraction-sdk/protocol-kit

this is my repo to try to get this working. I have a .env file with the 3 keys:
https://github.com/billyjitsu/safetest

I run `npx ts-node index.ts`  
And receive this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toHexString')

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your environment variables are available in **process.env**?
Maybe you should use the **dotenv** library?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/88325)